# Open keyboard android, hidden content phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I have problem when i open keyboard from android.

I am using phonegap to make a mobile application, It works well, but when i press a text box and open the keyboard, later when i close the keyboard leave blank the same size keyboard.

I 've looked everywhere and can not find the solution

Please help me!!!

attached screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your question is really interesting but is missing some infos in order to help you. Instead of posting big picture, can you please explain what have you tried ? Adding plugin etc ?

Comment: I have not used plugins. I have made ​​changes to the css in the config.xml and the AndroidManifest , but nothing has worked . ahhh , and that happens after that first open each screen , I mean the first time does not happen, but I open the screen again and I the problem appears.

Comment: And what have you changed exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 years I answer the question ... A little late. Suddenly it can be useful for someone.
I never found the reason why this happened. The only solution was to recreate a project from scratch, and pass the content that it had to the new project. I configured everything and it worked without problems.
I also installed crosswalk, I could have influenced the solution the problem.

Comment: I am too facing the same issue. What is the solution ? also on open of keyboard the input fields are not scrolling up